# Verifying Date/Time Input in PHP

Tags: php, date, format, verify

New to programming in PHP. Trying to verify input format for a date/time. User input is as follows for Nov 27 2012 at 6 PM '2012-nov-27|6pm'.

Not really sure where to start. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, which one of Nov 27 2012 at 6 PM and '2012-nov-27|6pm' will be your input and which your output?

Comment: '2012-nov-27|6pm' is the input

Comment: okay, I'm not sure exactly what you want when you say "verify input format", but to break it up you'd do this:
$input = '2012-nov-27|6pm';
$datetime = explode('|', $input);
$time = $datetime[1];
$input = $datetime[0];
$date=explode('-', $input);
$year = $date[0];
$mth = $date[1];
$day = $date[2];

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) for date_parse_from_format documentation and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for general date formatting. Give this a try:

```
<?php
$date = "2012-nov-27|6pm";
print_r(date_parse_from_format("Y-M-d|ga", $date));
?>
```

Comment: Do you know why I get an error (`Unexpected data found.`) in the resulting array? This doesn't happen if I replace the `|` by a `[space]`.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Gangnam</del> OOP style:

```
$input = '2012-nov-27|6pm';
$date  = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-M-j ga', str_replace('|', ' ', $input));
if ($date === false) {
    throw new \Exception('Invalid date!');
}
```

**NOTE:** I experienced an issue by using `|` in format/date string, so that the `str_replace()`

**NOTE 2:** If input day format is `01-31` instead of `1-31`, replace the `j` with a `d` in `createFromFormat()` first parameter.

Comment: I believe you mean OOP Gangnam Style. ROFL nice touch though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [checkdate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php):

```
if(checkdate($month, $day, $year)){
    echo 'Valid date!';
}
```

Or, you can convert whatever the user enters with strtotime(). If strtotime can't determine what the date is, it returns bool false.

```
if(strtotime($dateEntered) !== false){
     echo 'Valid date!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the format, use a regex:

```
$months = 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|okt|nov|dec';
$pattern = '/([0-9]{4})-('.$months.')-([0-9]{2})\\|([0-9]?[0-9])(am|pm)/';
preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

If you really want to check if a specific date/time exists, thing become more complicated. I may be wrong, but I don't think it can be done using PHP date functions, as they are quite tolerant to input errors. Maybe there's a library to do this.

Comment: This is a good attempt, however it does leave some error. since the month portion allows a-z the date could be any random 3 letters and still pass.

Comment: If I used this to check the correct input, could I use a separate date function such as checkdate() to ensure the validity of the date?

Comment: Edited. I split it up into variables to make it more readable here. Feel free to inline them again. I also added parentheses so you get the different parts in `$matches` afterwards to check them further. I can't give any advice on that, as dates are not PHP's strong side.

Comment: That will match `0000-jan-99|99am` as a valid date. You can validate dates with regex but it is far from being a trivial matter (how would you deal with leap years?). The easiest/faster way to check for valid dates is [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or `date_create_from_format()`, if you prefer it procedural.

Comment: If you think that, then run `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '0000-01-99 99:00:00')` and be surprised. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$datetime = "2012-nov-27|6pm";
$unixtime = strtotime( $datetime );
if( is_numeric($unixtime) && $unixtime <= PHP_INT_MAX ) {
  //do something if true
 } else {
    echo "Invalid DateTime";
 }
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/SWhDDiWH)

Comment: How would `$date_time` be an instanceof DateTime ever in this scenario? Isn't it just a string?

Comment: So, in this case, it will evaluate to *false*.

Comment: It will always evaluate to false. It's just a STRING! No matter what the strings contents are it will be false.

Comment: It seems `strtotime()` always return `false` if the input date contains a `|`. This does not happen if you put an `[space]` instead.

Comment: Yes, the OP doesn't mention, if he/she wants to remove `|` so I am assuming, he/she wants to retain it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to test your date for validity, the following will work.  Even if you were just looking to test the input format, I suggest you also sanity check the data as well.

```
$thedate = "2012-nov-27|6pm";

$arryParts = explode("|", $thedate);

$arryDate = date_parse($arryParts[0]);
if(!checkdate($arryDate['month'], $arryDate['day'], $arryDate['year'])) {
   /* error handling */
}

/* valid date, continue processing */
```